# Finding the mean of a value based on multiple variables

Tags: r, mean

[Plot of Reads vs Gelscores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxoYS.jpg)Mean #Reads for each permutation of gelscore?

I work in a genetics lab at my university, currently doing data analysis in our computer lab. After running PCR we scored our gels according to Band, Smear, Primer Dimer, and Non Specific Product. These variables where only assigned values of 0,1,or 2. I am trying to find the mean number of reads(sequencing results) returned for each combination of the 4 gel-scores. Each variable has its own column in the datasheet.

Datasheet:
Vial ID, Band, Smear, Primer.Dimer, Non.Spec, Reads

Ex. Mean number of reads for gels where Band=0, Smear=0, PrimerDimer=0 NonSpec=0.

Ex. Mean number of reads for gels where Band=0, Smear=1, PrimerDimer=1 NonSpec=2.

Etc.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you

I can plot this data using the generic plot function. Although the mean bars are displayed, I cannot ascertain their values.

"plot(Reads~as.factor(datasheet$Band+(Primer.Dimer*10)+(Smear*100)+(Non.Specific.Product*1000))"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the dplyr and tidyr packages:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)

    set.seed(14592)

    df <- data.frame(
      vial_id      = 1:10, 
      band         = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE), 
      smear        = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE), 
      primer_dimer = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE), 
      non_spec     = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE), 
      reads        = rnorm(10)
    )

   df %>% 
      unite(group_id, band:non_spec, remove = FALSE) %>% 
      group_by(group_id) %>% 
      summarize(group_mean = mean(reads))
```

This uses tidyr's `unite` function to create a unique group id for each combination of gel scores then uses dplyr's `group_by` and `summarize` functions to find the mean read for each group.